# Implementing android service that runs indefinitely, downloads data on regular interval

Tags: java, android, service

I'm developing an app that runs in the background, and does an API call every 5 minutes to download some data. I implemented a regular service with a Runnable in onStartCommand() that has a while(true) loop that runs forever. It has a Thread.sleep with a delay of 5 minutes in it.

I feel like this isn't the best way to do it (seems battery inefficient), but I'm not sure how else to do it. I'm also concerned about what would happen if the phone fell asleep. I read a bit on it, and read that I had to acquire partial wakelocks, but I'm not sure where I would put them in my code.

Comment: You should look into sync adapters http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean downloading data in that sense, it's a simple one line of code that calls an API.